# Facebook Fanpage Wallposting from C# App

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I have the following challenge at hand:

I have a fanpage for a apartment renting company. They would like to autoupdate their fanpage everytime a new apartment is added to the system.

The system is developed in C# ASP.NET 3.5.

I have downloaded the Facebook C# API From codeplex.

Have anyone done this, or know how to do it?

UPDATE:

So far I have tried the following:

```
        FacebookSession session = new Facebook.Session.ConnectSession(myKey,mySecretKey);

        Stream stream = new Stream(session);
        stream.Publish("Testing", null, null, null, 107010519323711);
```

I get a null reference Exception when I call Stream.Publish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is use the [RSS Graffiti](http://hu-hu.connect.facebook.com/RSS.Graffiti) page app. It will update your page profile from an RSS feed that you create.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _connectSession = new ConnectSession(API_KEY_HERE, FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY_HERE);
if (_connectSession.IsConnected())
{
    var _facebookApi = new Api(_connectSession);
    _facebookApi.Stream.Publish("Your text here", null, null, string.Empty, USER_ID_OR_PAGE_ID_TO_TARGET);
}
```

That code should work. Keep in mind your application needs to have permission to write to the wall of your target, however. You can get the permission via a "Facebook Connect" dialog, or probably through some other means that is slipping my mind at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a work around here.. I made a RSS feed and fed it to an application called RSS Grafitti. Very simple and works well.

Answer (score 0):

The following link should help.

http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/simple-5-steps-to-publish-on-a-facebook-wall-using-dotnet-c/

To allow whatever you want to do you will have to request extended permissions in the facebook connect javascript.